# Gradle project sync failed in Flutter project

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, gradle, firebase-mlkit

Every time my gradle is syncing it gets errors like this. Can someone help me?
Error cause after adding firebase_ml_vision dependency.

Caused by: org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.gradle.internal.crash.ExternalApiUsageException: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer$TaskCreationException: Could not create task ':app:packLibsflutterBuildDebug'.
Caused by: com.android.build.gradle.internal.crash.ExternalApiUsageException: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer$TaskCreationException: Could not create task ':app:packLibsflutterBuildDebug'.
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer$TaskCreationException: Could not create task ':app:packLibsflutterBuildDebug'.
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MissingMethodExecutionFailed: No signature of method: org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.destinationDir() is applicable for argument types: (File) values: [C:\Users\37499\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_ml_demo\build\app\intermediates\flutter\debug]

I tried changing gradle, java and firebase versions but that don't help.

Comment: It's failing for me too when I upgrade to Android gradle pulgin version 7.4.1 & gradle version 8.01 for the default flutter project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem caused by some deprecated dependencies on Firebase ML by creating a new project and using new dependencies that utilize Google ML Kit instead.

Answer (score 1):

It's failing for me too when I upgrade to Android gradle pulgin version 7.4.1 & gradle version 8.01 for the default flutter project.

*** I way to workaround for now.

Revert back to gradle version 7.6.

Upgrade to Android gradle pulgin version 7.4.1
Run all recomended upgrade steps (kotlin & others)

Tested for the default flutter project.

Update it to 8.0.1 later in about a month. (or until it is resolved by Gradle Team)